# While Loop in C# with Switch Statement

Tags: c#, if-statement, while-loop

I am trying to loop the switch condition if the choice is out of range. But i am not getting the desired output. So if while going through the switch condition the user does not input 1-3 as input, i want it to go to default condition which should trigger the error statement and then keep looping

```
Console.WriteLine("Which book would you like to check out?");
Console.WriteLine("select 1 for book 1, 2 for book 2, and 3 for book 3");

int choice=Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

bool loopBreak = true;
while (true)
{
    switch (choice)
    {

        case 1:
            Console.WriteLine("You have chosen book 1 {0}", b1.name);
            b1.CheckinCheckout = false;

            break;


        case 2:
            Console.WriteLine("You have chosen book 2 {0}", b2.name);
            b2.CheckinCheckout = false;

            break;

        case 3:
            Console.WriteLine("You have chosen book 3 {0}", b3.name);
            b3.CheckinCheckout = false;

            break;
        default:
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter a valid choice.");
            loopBreak = false;
            break;
    }
    if (loopBreak != false)
    {

        break;
    }
}
```

Updated:

```
bool loopBreak=true;
while (loopBreak==true)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Which book would you like to check out?");
    Console.WriteLine("select 1 for book 1, 2 for book 2, and 3 for book 3");
    int choice = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    switch (choice)
    {

        case 1:
            Console.WriteLine("You have chosen book 1 {0}", b1.name);
            b1.CheckinCheckout = false;

            break;


        case 2:
            Console.WriteLine("You have chosen book 2 {0}", b2.name);
            b2.CheckinCheckout = false;

            break;

        case 3:
            Console.WriteLine("You have chosen book 3 {0}", b3.name);
            b3.CheckinCheckout = false;

            break;
        default:
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter a valid choice.");
            loopBreak = false;
            break;
    }
    break;
}
```

Comment: You need to set loopbreak to true at the beginning of your loop, not before the loop ;) The same goes for your Readline-Call.

Comment: If you want to get again the input in case of a value different from 1,2,3 then you need to move your choice setting inside the loop (as well as any kind of message for your user "Which book would you like to check out?"

Comment: Consider also that you shouldn't trust your user to type a number. If he/she types a letter then the Convert.ToInt32 will raise an exception. In these cases always use Int32.TryParse

Comment: still can't get it to loop back to initial question and input even after moving statements inside loop. I've listed an updated code up top.

Comment: You should remove the final break but you also need to set loopbreak = false in each condition that you want to exit the loop while setting it to true in the condition where you want to repeat the loop

Comment: @Steve didn't quite understand. Can you show example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the boolean to false when you want to exit from the loop and do nothing when you want to continue asking for a valid input.

```
loopContinue = true;
while (loopContinue)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Which book would you like to check out?");
    Console.WriteLine("select 1 for book 1, 2 for book 2, and 3 for book 3");
    // Use TryParse when reading the user input. This will avoid an 
    // Exception if the user types a letter for example.
    if(Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), int out choice)
    {
        switch (choice)
        {
            case 1:
               ....
               loopContinue = false;
               break;
            case 2:
               ....
               loopContinue = false;
               break;
            case 3:
               ....
               loopContinue = false;
               break;

            // not really needed, if you remove the default
            // then your loop will not exit and you can start again
            default:
               loopContinue = true;
               break;
    }
    if(loopContinue)
         Console.WriteLine("Please enter a valid choice.");
}
```