# switch while won't loop

Tags: c#, loops, switch-statement

This is part of a program I'm writting. My main porblem is that once it goes trough one of the cases, tit won't loop so it's useless as it is. Any help? (Sorry for the variables in Spanish, also a couple of functions i created appear in the cose which are in the program and work just fine so I don't thin they have anything to do with the problem).

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int minutos_restantes = 480;
        int opcion;
        int valorComercial = 0;
        Tarea[] listado_tareas = new Tarea[10];

        CrearTareas(ref listado_tareas);

        Console.WriteLine("1. Mostrar tareas. \n2. Asignar tarea \n3. Salir, \n Elige opción: ");
        opcion = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        switch (opcion)
        {
            case 1:
                Imprimirtareas(listado_tareas);
                break;

            case 2:
                Console.WriteLine("Seleccionar número de tarea: ");
                int n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine())-1;

                if (n < 0 || n > 10)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("TAREA INEXISTENTE");
                }

                else if (listado_tareas[n].realizada == true)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("TAREA YA REALIZADA");
                }

                else if((minutos_restantes - listado_tareas[n].tiempo) <= 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("TIEMPO INSUFICIENTE");
                }

                else
                {
                    listado_tareas[n].realizada = true;
                    minutos_restantes -= listado_tareas[n].tiempo;
                }

                break;
        } while (opcion != 3) ;

    }
```

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47251045/while-loop-in-c-sharp-with-switch-statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can loop over a switch like this.
Try doing the while separate:

```
do
{
    switch (opcion)
    {
        case 1:
            Imprimirtareas(listado_tareas);
            break;

        case 2:
            Console.WriteLine("Seleccionar número de tarea: ");
            int n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine())-1;

            if (n < 0 || n > 10)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("TAREA INEXISTENTE");
            }

            else if (listado_tareas[n].realizada == true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("TAREA YA REALIZADA");
            }

            else if((minutos_restantes - listado_tareas[n].tiempo) <= 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("TIEMPO INSUFICIENTE");
            }

            else
            {
                listado_tareas[n].realizada = true;
                minutos_restantes -= listado_tareas[n].tiempo;
            }

            break;
    } 

}while (opcion != 3) ;
```

Comment: Using the new pattern matching, those else if's can be made part of the switch/case.

Answer (score 1):

There's no such construct:

```
switch
{

} while (...);
```

In C#. What you've actually written is:

```
switch
{

}
while (...);
```

Which is another way of writing

```
switch
{

}

while (...)
{

}
```

I suspect you want to put your switch statement inside a while or a do...while loop.

Answer (score 0):

Go for something like this:

```
int opcion = 0;
do
{
    opcion = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    switch (opcion)
    {
        ...
    }
} while (opcion != 3);
```

Check this one too: [While Loop in C# with Switch Statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47251045/while-loop-in-c-sharp-with-switch-statement)

Answer (score 0):

This is broken code.
You have a `switch() {}` statement (without `default` and those `break`s cause you to fall out of its scope) and a `while (condition) /*do nothing*/;` statement.

The intention is `do{switch(){}}while()` ?

Time to do some reading...

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/switch

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/while

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/do

Answer (score 0):

You should do :-

```
while (condition)
{
     switch
     {

     }
}
```