# How to rerun a code again in switch statement

Tags: c#, switch-statement

**Objective**: Request users to input yes or no again when they type "idk" until they reply yes or no, how to rerun the `ask` and `ans` above?

**Requirement**: Not to use boolean.

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string ask = "Yes or No?";
    Console.WriteLine(ask);
    string ans = Console.ReadLine();
    switch(ans)
    {
        case "yes":
        yes();
        break;
        case "no":
        no();
        break;
        case "idk":
        //run "ask" again
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [While Loop in C# with Switch Statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47251045/while-loop-in-c-sharp-with-switch-statement)

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm.. Normally you would use booleans and loop while the boolean is still true and set it to false when you get what you want.

But if you want to avoid booleans you can use an infinite loop and just return out of the function you are in when you are done:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string ask = "Yes or No?";
        
        for (;;)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ask);
            string ans = Console.ReadLine();
    
            switch(ans.ToLower())
            {
                case "yes":
                    yes();
                    return;
                
                case "no":
                    no();
                    return;
            }
        }
    }

    static void yes() => Console.WriteLine("Yes selected");
    static void no() => Console.WriteLine("No selected");
}
```

Comment: Thankyou very much

Comment: No problem, if this helped, please mark it as the Answer.

Answer (score 0):

> I will be suggesting you use a do-while loop rather then goto statment

```
static void Main(string[] args)
            {
    
               
            NotFound:
                string ask = "Yes or No?";
                Console.WriteLine(ask);
                string ans = Console.ReadLine();
                switch (ans)
                {
                    case "yes":
                        yes();
                        break;
                    case "no":
                        no();
                        break;
                    case "idk":
                        goto NotFound;                   
                }
    
               
                   
            }
    
            private static void no()
            {
                
            }
    
            private static void yes()
            {
                 
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  switch(exp) 
  {
    case "+":
      Console.WriteLine("Enter Yor Number");
      int PlusA = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
      Console.WriteLine("Enter Yor Number");
      int PlusB = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
      Console.WriteLine("Answer =");
      Console.WriteLine(PlusA + PlusB);
```

One more question I want to make a plus calculator, I want to let the user type more then 2 numbers, until they type the symbol `;` how to do that?